# How to make tabs with nested React Router v6 routing?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have following routing for parent route `/files`:

```
/files
  | - /raw-medias
  | - /datasets
```

Route `/files` renders tabs for child routes and by default redirects to child route `./raw-medias`. Each child route has a list with clickable items. On item click opens item page. There's a Back Button on that page.

Problem: if a user clicks on Datasets tab, then click on item in a list and then click on Back Button then Raw Media tab is active even though the user is on correct route `/files/datasets` (`Datasets` tab should be active).

How can I fix that?

Even though `files/raw-medias/:rawMediaId` and `files/datasets/:datasetId` are children of `/files` route I placed them outside in router because they should use `HomePage.tsx` `<Outlet />` (the same as `/files` route).

**Codesanbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-make-tabs-routing-with-react-router-v6-with-cross-linking-on-nested-page-forked-6efytj?file=/src/HomePage.tsx

**router**

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <HomePage />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/files",
        element: <FilesPage />,
        children: [
          {
            path: "raw-medias",
            element: <RawMediaList data={RAW_DATA} />
          },
          {
            path: "datasets",
            element: <DatasetList data={DATASET_DATA} />
          },

          {
            index: true,
            element: <Navigate to="./raw-medias" replace />
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: "files/raw-medias/:rawMediaId",
        element: <RawMediaPage />
      },
      {
        path: "files/datasets/:datasetId",
        element: <DatasetPage />
      }
    ]
  }
]);
```

**FilesPage.tsx**

```
const FilesPage = () => {
  const [tab, setTab] = useState<Tabs>("rawMedia");

  const handleTabs = (
    event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>,
    tab: Tabs | null
  ) => {
    if (tab !== null) {
      setTab(tab);
    }
  };
  return (
    <Stack>
        <ToggleButtonGroup value={tab} onChange={handleTabs} exclusive>
          <ToggleButton
            value={"rawMedia"}
            component={NavLink}
            to={"raw-medias"}
          >
            RAW Media
          </ToggleButton>
          <ToggleButton value={"dataset"} component={NavLink} to={"datasets"}>
            Datasets
          </ToggleButton>
        </ToggleButtonGroup>
      <Stack>
        <Outlet />
      </Stack>
    </Stack>
  );
};
```

**UPD**

I tried this in `FilesPage.tsx` and it seems fixes the problem. But another bug appears. If user clicks on another parent route (like `/` and then back on `/files` then no tabs is highlighted. I think this happens because of redirect from `/files` to `./raw-media` but don't know how to fix it.

```
  const userLocation = location?.pathname?.split('/').at(-1) as Tabs;

  const [tab, setTab] = useState<Tabs>(userLocation);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize the `tab` state from the current `location.pathname` value. Use a `useEffect` hook to ensure the `tab` state is updated when the path changes externally, i.e. from the back button or other links not a tab button.

Example:

```
import {
  Stack,
  Typography,
  ToggleButton,
  ToggleButtonGroup
} from "@mui/material";
import { NavLink, Outlet, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

type Tabs = "raw-medias" | "datasets";

const FilesPage = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  const [tab, setTab] = useState<Tabs>(pathname.split("/")?.pop() as Tabs);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTab(pathname.split("/")?.pop() as Tabs);
  }, [pathname]);

  const handleTabs = (
    event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>,
    tab: Tabs | null
  ) => {
    if (tab !== null) {
      setTab(tab);
    }
  };
  return (
    <Stack gap={"30px"}>
      <Typography variant="h4" align={"center"}>
        FilesPage
      </Typography>
      <Stack direction={"row"} gap={"10px"}>
        <ToggleButtonGroup value={tab} onChange={handleTabs} exclusive>
          <ToggleButton
            value={"raw-medias"}
            component={NavLink}
            to={"raw-medias"}
          >
            RAW Media
          </ToggleButton>
          <ToggleButton value={"datasets"} component={NavLink} to={"datasets"}>
            Datasets
          </ToggleButton>
        </ToggleButtonGroup>
      </Stack>

      <Stack>
        <Outlet />
      </Stack>
    </Stack>
  );
};

export default FilesPage;
```

[image: Edit how-to-make-tabs-with-nested-react-router-v6-routing]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works awesome. By the way, what do you think about this solution? Which one is better yours or this `const userLocation = pathname === '/files' ? 'raw-media' : pathname?.split('/').pop() as Tabs`. Then  `<ToogleButton value={userLocation} />` (no need for useState, handleTabs and useEffect)

Comment: @qweezz Ah, you're right, I don't think a React state and `useEffect` is necessary here. Better is subjective. Often this pattern is indicative of just using the `useMemo` hook to create a stable reference, otherwise just directly computing it is sufficient. I just sort of kept your state in there without any optimization.

Comment: This will not work if you have nested routes within your tabs

Comment: @MiguelCarvajal Can you be more specific about what wouldn't work if there are further nested routes?

Comment: @DrewReese you are doing `pathname.split("/")?.pop()` to get the last segment of the url and match it against the tab. But if inside the tab body you render another route you may have  a location that looks like `basePath/tabPath/subpath`.

Comment: @MiguelCarvajal The `pathname.split("/")?.pop()` is from the location of the current route, and if there isn't a sub-route match then the UI redirects to `"/files/raw-medias"`, there isn't a way to get another value. You could use the [matchPath](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/utils/match-path) utility to match the specific segment though. Something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-make-tabs-with-nested-react-router-v6-routing-forked-93mkwk?file=/src/FilesPage.tsx).

Answer (score 1):

I think perhaps try make `tab` completely dependent on path for a possible solution.

This way, it gets updated by `useMatch` and should work without `useState` and `onChange` for manual handling of changes.

The below example uses a simple condition to check paths just for demonstration, but can work with more specific logic in the actual use case.

If there are more tabs to be added to the project, consider make them `params` in router so that it would be easier to get the values with `useParams` and set condition logic.

Example: (forked live on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-make-tabs-routing-with-react-router-v6-with-cross-linking-on-nested-page-forked-szfsvk?file=/src/FilesPage.tsx))

```
import { useMatch  } from "react-router-dom";

const match = useMatch({ path: "files/datasets" });
const pathTab = match ? "dataset" : "rawMedia";

<ToggleButtonGroup value={pathTab} exclusive>
...
</ToggleButtonGroup>
```

Comment: In codesandbox example there are only 2 tabs. Actually I have three in my project and going to have more. I'm not sure if this soution will work or be easy to maintain.

Comment: @qweezz Indeed, this is only based on posted code and probably need to adjust the condition logic in actual use case. Perhaps calculate a `tab` value from `pathname`  is possible if the actual tabs are named in same pattern. Anyways, hope that this still help as a reference.

Comment: @qweezz If there are many tabs perhaps also consider making them `params` so it would be easier to maintain and to check values for condition.